# limiting the number of occurrences of elements in 2-tuples

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to find a single set-based query solution in SQL (or postgresql 9.4) for the following problem:

I have a finite set of unique 2-tuples (x ∈ N, y ∈ N) which have a rank assigned.

Now I want to remove all tuples so that remaining tuples satisfy the following condition:

1. each number occurs a maximum of n times on the left side of a tuple and
2. each number occurs a maximum of m times on the right side.

This would be easy to do with a procedure that iterates over the ordered tuples and counts the number of occurrences of each element. However, I want to know if there is solution with a single (postgre)SQL-query?

To be more specific please consider the following simple example with n=2, m=2:

```
╔═══╦═══╦══════╗
║ x ║ y ║ rank ║
╠═══╬═══╬══════╣
║ 1 ║ 4 ║    1 ║
║ 2 ║ 4 ║    2 ║
║ 3 ║ 4 ║    3 ║
║ 3 ║ 5 ║    4 ║
║ 3 ║ 6 ║    5 ║
║ 3 ║ 7 ║    6 ║
╚═══╩═══╩══════╝
```

Now we are looking for a query that returns the following tuples as result: (1,4), (2,4), (3,5), (3,6)

SQL fiddle for the table and values:

```
   create table tab (
     x bigint,
     y bigint,
     rank bigint);

  insert into tab values (1,4,1);
  insert into tab values (2,4,2);
  insert into tab values (3,4,3);
  insert into tab values (3,5,4);
  insert into tab values (3,6,5);
  insert into tab values (3,7,6);
```

I've tried an approach using a postgres window function, which solves the above example, but I am not sure yet if it can find as many pairs as the cursor-based approach for other examples.

```
    SELECT x, y FROM (
      SELECT x, y, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY rank) AS rx FROM (
        SELECT x, y, rank, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY rank) AS ry FROM tab) AS limitY
      WHERE limitY.ry < 3) AS limitX
    WHERE limitX.rx < 3
```

Comment: When you say, "declarative", do you mean a single set-based query? "Declarative" in the context of SQL usually means declarative RI, which would be a very different thing.

Comment: Yes, I mean a single set-based query. I am looking for a solution following the declarative programming approach rather than an imperative one using a stored procedure.

Comment: Could there be elements in x or y out of order (when sorted by rank)? If not, can the rank be trusted to be perfectly sequential?

Comment: You can assume that x and y are always ordered by rank ascending (that their values are in order is just a coincidence here to keep the example simple), however I have done some more work on this problem and would need to add another condition to the initial 2 (maximizing the amount of pairs returned) which changes the scope significantly. Should I just edit my original post or create a follow up question?

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation using a single window-function pass (may be faster):

```
select x, y, rank
from (
  select *, count(*) over (partition by x order by rank) as cx,
            count(*) over (partition by y order by rank) as cy
  from tab
  order by rank
  ) t
where cx < 3 and cy < 3;
```

There's also the recursive CTE approach:

```
-- use tab directly instead of tabr CTE (and replace all ocurrences of r column with rank)
-- if rank is trusted to be sequential uninterrupted starting with 1
with recursive
  r (r, x, y, rank, cx, cy) as (
    select *, 1 as cx, 1 as cy
    from tabr where r = 1
    union all
    select t.*, case when r.x = t.x then r.cx + 1 else 1 end as cx, case when r.y = t.y then r.cy + 1 else 1 end as cy
    from r, tabr t
    where t.r = r.r + 1
    ),
  tabr as (
    select row_number() over () as r, *
    from tab
    order by rank
    )
select x, y, rank
from r
where cx <= 2 and cy <= 2
order by r;
```

Comment: Your first solution discounts the fact that (3, 6) will be valid since (3,4) has already been excluded due to y, so the count of x=3 changes. I don't know if the second solution has the same error or not.

Answer (score 0):

This one took awhile, but I was able to come up with a solution in MS SQL Server, which I think should translate to PostGreSQL. SQL Server has some constraints on what can be in recursive CTEs and I don't fully know what constraints PostGreSQL has. That said, hopefully this works for you or points you in the right direction.

The tricky part was that the excluded rows changed based on rows that had already been excluded, so they couldn't be calculated simply and because they relied on both x **and** y, the recursive CTE couldn't just build in order since it could only reference itself once. That's when I came up with the idea of embedding the counts in a string. This doesn't scale well at all - for example, if the rule changes to 3 or 4 instances before a row is excluded then the `CASE` statements start to explode.

```
WITH CTE_Excludes AS
(
    SELECT
        x,
        y,
        [rank],
        CAST('|' + CAST(x AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-1|' AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS x_counts,
        CAST('|' + CAST(y AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-1|' AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS y_counts,
        0 AS excluded
    FROM
        tab
    WHERE
        [rank] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        T.x,
        T.y,
        T.[rank],
        CAST(CASE
            WHEN X.x_counts LIKE '%|' + CAST(T.x AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-2|%' OR X.y_counts LIKE '%|' + CAST(T.y AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-2|%' THEN X.x_counts
            WHEN X.x_counts LIKE '%|' + CAST(T.x AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-1|%' THEN REPLACE(X.x_counts, '|' + CAST(T.x AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-1|', '|' + CAST(T.x AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-2|')
            ELSE X.x_counts + '|' + CAST(T.x AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-1|'
        END AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS x_counts,
        CAST(CASE
            WHEN X.x_counts LIKE '%|' + CAST(T.x AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-2|%' OR X.y_counts LIKE '%|' + CAST(T.y AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-2|%' THEN X.y_counts
            WHEN X.y_counts LIKE '%|' + CAST(T.y AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-1|%' THEN REPLACE(X.y_counts, '|' + CAST(T.y AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-1|', '|' + CAST(T.y AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-2|')
            ELSE X.y_counts + '|' + CAST(T.y AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-1|'
        END AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS y_counts,
        CASE
            WHEN X.x_counts LIKE '%|' + CAST(T.x AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-2|%' OR X.y_counts LIKE '%|' + CAST(T.y AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-2|%' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS excluded
    FROM
        CTE_Excludes X
    INNER JOIN tab T ON T.[rank] = X.[rank] + 1
)
SELECT
    x, y
FROM
    CTE_Excludes
WHERE
    excluded = 0
```